# Reorder a list of dataframes before rbind (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working with R and I have a problem with rbinding dataframe.
My data come from a Json file and the first think I have done is to split it accordingly to Chromosome number

```
#Input
Control <- fromJSON(file=O5)
RNAi <- fromJSON(file=s25p5)

#Loop throug each chromosome
Control.1 <- lapply(Control, function(I)
        {
        data.frame(matrix(unlist(I),ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE))
})
```

The problem is that now I have a list of 6 data.frame but on a random order

```
str(Control.1)

List of 6

  $ II    :'data.frame':    1771887 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ matrix.unlist.I...ncol...1..byrow...TRUE.: num [1:1771887] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ I    :'data.frame':  1507243 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ matrix.unlist.I...ncol...1..byrow...TRUE.: num [1:1507243] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ III  :'data.frame':  1378370 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ matrix.unlist.I...ncol...1..byrow...TRUE.: num [1:1378370] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

etc.
```

I would like to reorder them in order to have $I as the first data.frame, then $II etc.

my aim is to use rbind after

```
Control.2 <-do.call(rbind,Control.1)
```

in order to have one data frame containing all the data frame but in the correct oder.

Does anybody have any idea how it could be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

for alphabetical order you can use :

```
Control.2 <-do.call(rbind,Control.1[order(names(Control.1)))
```

or you can use any other function than order to sort the names vector.